# Regex bold characters using *

Tags: javascript, regex

If I have text like:

`I need to bold *this* text and *that* text.`

I need to bold **this** text and **that** text.

I need to convert both to `<b>this</b>` and `<b>that</b>`.

```
var str = $('textarea#commentfield').val();
var getBold = str.match(/\*.+\*/g);
if(getBold!=null){
  getBold = getBold.toString().replace(/\*/g,"");
}
str = str.replace(/\*[^*]+?\*/g, "<b>"+getBold+"<\/b>");
```

This is not doing what I want for 2 or more matches. It's doing this instead:

I need to bold **this text and that** text and **this text and that** text.

Comment: Sorry, looking at too many questions, though the line was split/exploded, will delete so as not mislead

Comment: `"I need to bold *this* text and *that* text.".replace(/\*([^*]+)\*/g,"<b>$1</b>")`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just use a capture group and a group reference number :

```
str =str.replace(/\*([^*]+)\*/g, "<b>$1<\/b>");
```

Comment: @frosty Did you reassigned it to `str`?

Comment: @Kasra You don't need for `?` here.

Comment: @AvinashRaj Why? it should be non-greedy!!

Comment: non-greedy? Then why you used the negated char class ? Ya, non-greedy is applicable only if you use `.*` because `.` would match any char including `*` but `[^*]` won't.

Comment: @AvinashRaj Ah, yeah very thanks! I'm always care about that but in this case as OP has putted it already i missed that!

Comment: What would you do if you wanted to bold with two `**`?

Comment: @frosty So just use 2 * ;) `/\*\*([^*]+)\*\*/g`

Comment: I wanted to do bold as one * and underline as two, but unfortunately using both doesn't seem to work. I'll use a different character for each.

Answer (score 2):

Simply use closure to keep track of the tag state while you replace each star:

```js
function embolden(str) {
  var open = false;
  var ret = str.replace(/\*/g, function() {
    if (open) {
      open = false;
      return '</b>';
    } else {
      open = true;
      return '<b>';
    }
  });
  if (open) {
    ret += '</b>';
  }
  return ret;
}


var input = 'I need to bold *this* text and *that* text.';
document.getElementById('r').innerHTML = embolden(input);
```

```html
<pre id=r></pre>
```

This saves you any weird escaping rules, and unbalanced tags can easily be avoided by checking the state before returning.

Comment: Shouldn't you be setting innerHTML?

Comment: @epascarello I'm not sure which works better for a demo (pre + textContent gives you the actual output).

Answer (score 0):

. * **bold** * and \n **break**

```
function(sting){
    let  str = sting.replace(/\*([^*]+)\*/g, "<b>$1<\/b>");
    return str.replace(/\n/g, "<br />");
}
```